# How to get Customer default shipping address in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, shipping

I want to get Customer default shipping address in Magento 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is the sample code of how you get the default shipping address information of the customer**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory;

class MyClass
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var AddressRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $addressRepository;

    /**
     * @var CountryFactory
     */
    private $countryFactory;

    /**
     * MyClass constructor.
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param CountryFactory $countryFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        CountryFactory $countryFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->countryFactory = $countryFactory;
    }


    public function getShippingInfo()
    {
        $customerId = 1;
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        $shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();

        $shippingAddress = $this->addressRepository->getById($shippingAddressId);

        echo $shippingAddress->getRegion()->getRegion(); // Get region
        echo $shippingAddress->getCity(); // Get city
        echo $shippingAddress->getPostcode(); // Get postcode

        //Get country name
        $countryCode = $shippingAddress->getCountryId();
        $country = $this->countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode);
        echo $country->getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Prince bro Thank you it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and let me know if you need more details.

```
$customerRepository = Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
$addressRepository = Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface
//define above variables in constructor.
 $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
 $shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();

//get default billing address
 try {
    $shippingAddress = $this->addressRepository->getById($shippingAddressId);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how to get city and street address all filed value.

Comment: or try this $shippingAddress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress(); 
echo $shippingAddress->getCountryId();
echo '<br>';
echo $shippingAddress->getCity();
echo '<br>';
echo $shippingAddress->getRegionId();
echo '<br>';
echo $shippingAddress->getRegion();

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
$customerRepository = Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
$addressRepository = Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface
//define above variables in constructor.
 $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
 $shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();

//get default billing address
 try {
    $shippingAddress = $this->addressRepository->getById($shippingAddressId);
    $shippingAddress->getCity();
    $shippingAddress->getStreet();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //
}
```

accept as a solution if works so other can find out right code.